# Key generation using byte[] generates different results for MAC and Windows

Tags: java, windows, macos, encryption, bouncycastle

I am trying to generate keys using byte[] i.e. from a string.
My class is final and I have the methods static.

Class:

```
public final class Operation {

    public static Key getKey(byte[] arr)
    {
        Key key = null;
    KeyGenerator keyGen;
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    try
    {
            keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES", "BC");
            if(arr == null)
                keyGen.init(192);
            else
                keyGen.init(new SecureRandom(arr));
            key = keyGen.generateKey();
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
    {
            System.err.println(e);  
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

        return key;
    }

    public static String getKeyAsString(Key key)
    {
        return  new String(Base64.encode(key.getEncoded()));
    }

    public static Key getKeyFromString(String string)
    {
        return new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decode(string.getBytes()), "AES");
    }

}
```

The main function has these lines :

```
    Key key1 = Operation.getKey("admin".getBytes());
    Key key2 = Operation.getKey("admin".getBytes());

    System.out.println(new String(Base64.encode(key1.getEncoded())));
    System.out.println(new String(Base64.encode(key2.getEncoded())));
```

I am getting the same output of keys on windows like:

```
4BjJkLCJ3LyPluKkd2DBgqghhNfSgzKD
4BjJkLCJ3LyPluKkd2DBgqghhNfSgzKD
```

but this is not the case with Mac OS.

Dependancy I am using is:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
<artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
<version>1.46</version>
</dependency>
```

Now I came to the point that the JDK version is the sole problem here.

On windows I have `JDK 1.7` whereas I have `JDK 1.6` on MAC. 
Is this really a JDK issue coz I am really stuck here.

Please help.

Comment: Yes, I tried both. With encoding and without encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I see different values in Linux. I think the reason is `SecureRandom`, check this out:

```
System.out.println(new SecureRandom("admin".getBytes()).nextLong());
System.out.println(new SecureRandom("admin".getBytes()).nextLong());
```

example output (changes every time):

```
1642139269925848082
2081201540941864354
```

From the javadoc:

> Many SecureRandom implementations are in the form of a pseudo-random
>   number generator (PRNG), which means they use a deterministic
>   algorithm to produce a pseudo-random sequence from a true random seed.
>   Other implementations may produce true random numbers, and yet others
>   may use a combination of both techniques.

Comment: Yes, That is because it calls the method nextLong() which will generate nextLong() randomly, right?? But why I am getting same keys on JDK 1.7 and not on 1.6 . I don't think OS has anything to do with this coz JVM works independently, right?

Comment: @ADi Well, the 2 SecureRandom instances were seeded with the same seed. If the implementation uses a PRNG then nextLong() will be the same, otherwise not. Different JVMs can have different SecureRandom implementations. Both the OS and the version could make a difference (as well as the author). Try running my code in your environments.

Comment: I tried that, its giving me different results. So does it mean I should stick to Windows with JDK 1.7 coz its serving my purpose?? :)

Comment: I don't think KeyGenerator is supposed to have deterministic output. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Long shot, I am implementing Kerberos of my own, I am at stage 1 where Authentication Server creates AES key using the password of user and will use it to encrypt the session key to send the packet back to user. Now The same key must be generated by User on its own. So here comes my code. I must get same keys to fulfill this.

Comment: Well, I think you could use a digester with a fixed salt or something similar. I don't know a lot about this stuff, I strongly suggest that you ask a separate question about how to generate a deterministic AES key from a user's password. You should probably mention Kerberos too :)

Comment: ok, thanks. Actually I just compared the both implementations of SecureRandom and found some differences. If I face the same issue again, I will surely go for a different option. Thanks again! :)